# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction, using persistence.xml in spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am getting the error that my EntityManager could not be opened:

nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

**root cause**

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="school"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="model"/>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

I am using hibernate + a persistence.xml file in the spring framework.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projecten2"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="/src/main/resources/META-INF/seed.sql"/>-->
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have been searching over the site and google but nothing looked as if they had the same kind of setup.

Console

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1207)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:445)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy360.findOne(Unknown Source)
    at controller.PlanningController.index(PlanningController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace? Also what versions of Spring and Hibernate are you using?

Comment: I am using hibernate 4.0.1.Final and Spring 3.2.3 RELEASE, i can't find a complete stacktrace because its not showing. However i updated the original post with a stacktrace of an error that pops up at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your persistence.xml change the line

```
<persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
```

to

```
<persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Also it would probably be best if you create a datasource bean in your Spring configuration instead of using implicitly in persistence.xml (that way you can easily switch datasources with Spring profiles)

Check out [this](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-jpa.jsp) tutorial for details

To fix your deployment issues on Glassfish, see [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/50303-transaction-type-jta-resource-local) and [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/594797/Spring/problems-deploying-Spring-Roo-file) link.
From those links one suggestion is to set the version in your web.xml to 2.4 and the other suggestion is to do perform a whole bunch of steps to get Spring to actually play with transaction-type="JTA".

Comment: I used to have it this way before but then i get this error:  `The persistence-context-ref-name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean/entityManager] in module [p2groep04-javaweb] resolves to a persistence unit called [myPersistenceUnit] which is of type RESOURCE_LOCAL. Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager. Please verify your application.`

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: I am using Glassfish 4.0

Comment: See my updated answer. Let me know what happens so I can update this answer accordingly for future users.

Comment: Okay, first of all thank you for your response. You helped me a lot solving my issue. The changes i have made were: I added `metadata-complete="true"` to `web.xml`. I changed the `transaction-type` back to `RESOURCE-LOCAL`. I also followed your advise to create a datasource bean. Now everything works fine :)

Comment: It helped me really greatly! +1 here and to some another answer of yours.

Comment: I would append one link here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30349784/715269, without those annotations from the question and the answer there it didn't work for me. Reading - yes, but not update or delete.